# PostgreSQL: How to select N random entries per column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

I have the following code

```
with my_table (id, student, category, score)
as (values 
(1, 'Alex', 'A', 11),
(2, 'Alex', 'D', 4),
(2, 'Alex', 'B', 50),
(2, 'Alex', 'C', 83),
(2, 'Alex', 'D', 5),
(3, 'Bill', 'A', 81),
(6, 'Carl', 'C', 5),
(7, 'Carl', 'D', 2),
(7, 'Carl', 'B', 21),
(7, 'Carl', 'A', 55),
(7, 'Carl', 'A', 86),
(7, 'Carl', 'D', 10)
)


select *,
     row_number() over (partition by student order by random()) as row_sort
from my_table
```

I would like to know how I can adjust it to return 2 random entries per student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value of window function can only be accessed after thwe query has run, so using a second CTE will do the trick

```
with my_table (id, student, category, score)
as (values 
(1, 'Alex', 'A', 11),
(2, 'Alex', 'D', 4),
(2, 'Alex', 'B', 50),
(2, 'Alex', 'C', 83),
(2, 'Alex', 'D', 5),
(3, 'Bill', 'A', 81),
(6, 'Carl', 'C', 5),
(7, 'Carl', 'D', 2),
(7, 'Carl', 'B', 21),
(7, 'Carl', 'A', 55),
(7, 'Carl', 'A', 86),
(7, 'Carl', 'D', 10)
),
CTE2 as (select *,
     row_number() over (partition by student order by random()) as row_sort
from my_table)
SELECT id, student, category, score
  FROM CTE2
WHERE row_sort <= 2
```

| id | student | category | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Alex | C | 83 |
| 2 | Alex | D | 5 |
| 3 | Bill | A | 81 |
| 7 | Carl | A | 86 |
| 7 | Carl | B | 21 |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SMZrngWg)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your select into outer one and add `where row_sort<=2`:

```sql
select id, student, category, score
  from(
select *,
     row_number() over (partition by student order by random()) as row_sort
from my_table) inner_t
where row_sort<=2
```

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/56ajjc09).

| id | student | category | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Alex | D | 5 |
| 2 | Alex | B | 50 |
| 3 | Bill | A | 81 |
| 7 | Carl | D | 10 |
| 7 | Carl | A | 55 |